# Translate SQL to LINQ

Tags: sql, linq

How would I translate the following SQL statement into a LINQ statement in C#?

```
select BLDG_CODE, count(ROOM) "Number of Rooms"
from LOCATION
group by BLDG_CODE;
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried anything? It's not *I need code, give it to me!* site...

Comment: I tried this: 
     var query = from l in Locations
                select new
                {
                    Id = f.FID,
                    Name = f.FLast,
                    Total = g.Count()
                };
    
    query.Dump();

Comment: actually disregard that, that was wrong. Just trying to write something else now.

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from l in Locations
            group l by l.BLDG_CODE into g
            select new { 
                BLGD_CODE = g.Key,
                NumberOfRooms = g.Count()
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you prefer Method Syntax...

```
var query = Locations.GroupBy(location => location.BLDG_CODE)
                     .Select(group => new {  
                                            BuildingCode = group.Key,
                                            NumberOfRooms = group.Count()
                                          });
```